# Setting Jenkins HOME on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, macos-mojave

No matter how I set the environment variable JENKINS_HOME, Jenkins seems to ignore it and point to the default home folder.

Im using Mac OS Mojave and used the installer downloaded from jenkins site. After installation it creates a new user (jenkins). I had followed many tutorials on how to set env variables on mac and currently am setting using launchctl like this

```
launchctl setenv JENKINS_HOME /My/Path
```

I had even create a file named environment.plist and set it to folders /Library/LaunchAgents and /Library/LaunchDaemons with the following contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>my.startup</string>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
 <string>sh</string>
 <string>-c</string>
 <string>launchctl setenv JENKINS_HOME /Volumes/transfer/jenkinshome</string>
 </array>
 <key>RunAtLoad</key>
 <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Doing echo $JENKINS_HOME print the correct path on terminal but yet the jenkins installation seems to ignore it.

So, how one does change jenkins home folder?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this !!

Comment: Hey @shadygoneinsane, yes I did, forgot to update the question. Check if it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer but only if you installed using the Mac installer (not brew).

First, stop jenkins

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Then change the home value in using defaults

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci "JENKINS_HOME "{YOURVALUE}"
```

Restart

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```